# Google cloud build use different env file from gs bucket for different environments

Tags: google-cloud-build

I am using Google cloud build to deploy the cloud functions.

But I have different env files for each environment(staging/prerelease/production).

Can anybody point me in the right direction to set up different env files on different environments.

I am thinking about storing the env file in different buckets for each environment and use it in cloud build to set the env variables by fetching the files from different buckets depending on which environment i am deploying to. I am not sure how to do this right now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact use case, you may consider using [GitHub triggers](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers) and have your Cloud Functions automatically deployed whenever you push a change to your repository.

This also allows you to separate your environments into 3 branches (staging/prerelease/production) and each of the trigger will listen to one of the triggers.

With this option you can even create separate triggers to listen to pull requests in case you want to merge contents between branches, very useful for example whenever you want to merge a change from staging to prerelase or even from prerelease to prod.

This approach is also faster than having to read/copy files from Cloud Storage and is more straightforward, Cloud Build just needs to deploy your Cloud Function as the whole environment files are stored at your GitHub repo.

Comment: Yes I am using the github triggers for the deployment, The problem is with setting env variables.Cannot store the envorinment files in the repo as there is secret api keys there which cannot be stored in the repo and is different api keys for each environment.

Comment: You can make use of [Secret Manager or KMS](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials) to encrypt and then decrypt the sensitive data and have everything specified on your yaml for example.

Comment: Using Cloud Storage for storing Plain Text secrets instead of having this in your Git repo isn't safer. Encrypt them with KMS or store them into secret manager. And prefer Git for your configuration, the versionning and the rollback are easier than with Cloud Storage